# Expected value inequality for a monotone function

Tags: probability, monotone-functions

A "simple" expected value inequality confuse me.

If $f(x)$ is a monotone increasing function defined on the interval $[a,b]$, and $c \in [a,b]$, is it possible to prove the following inequality?

$$\mathrm E\left(\sum_{t=a}^{c}f(t)\right)\leq \mathrm E \left(\sum_{t=a}^{b}f(t)\right)$$

Comment: I'm assuming $a,b,c$ are integers, otherwise those sums don't make sense.  What you want is simply that $E(f(t)) \ge 0$ for $c < t \le b$.

Comment: I must be missing something very simple here... What is the random variable? What is the expectation taken over?

Comment: Yanagi, do not repost a question. Ever. If you lost your login credentials, and therefore could not edit the first version, then read [the help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).