# Expectation inequality for a set and its subset.

Tags: real-analysis, expectation, monotone-functions

Given that a function $g(x)$ is a monotone increasing function. Its domain is an interval [c,d]. There are two sets $a_j \in A, j= 1,...,J$ and $b_k \in B,k=1,...,K$  on this interval, which satisfy $c_z \in C = B$\A and $c_z \geq a_j$ for all $a_j \in A$. For example, the interval $[c,d]=[0,8]$,$A=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. In this case, does the following inequality hold? If yes, could you give me some hints to prove that?

$$\frac{1}{K} \sum_{k=1}^{K}g(b_k) \geq \frac{1}{J} \sum_{j=1}^{J}g(a_j)$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics-SE. Can you tell us what have you thought so far, if so?

Comment: I have tried a simple example. $A=[1,2,3,4,5]$ and $B=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]$. My feeling is that the inequality should hold, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but how to prove it mathematically.

Comment: Is that the same question in disguise? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903674/expected-value-inequality-for-a-monotone-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take $g(x)=x$, $[c,d]=[0,1]$, $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{0,1\}$ 
then 
$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{K} \sum_{k=1}^{K}g(b_k) < \frac{1}{J} \sum_{j=1}^{J}g(a_j)=1.$$

On the other hand, if you assume that if $b\in B\setminus A$ then $b>\mu:=\frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{a\in A}g(a)$, it follows
$$\frac{1}{|B|} \sum_{b\in B}g(b)=\frac{1}{|B|} \sum_{a\in A}g(a)+\frac{1}{|B|} \sum_{b\in B\setminus A}g(b)\\
>\frac{|A|}{|B|} \cdot \mu+\frac{1}{|B|} \sum_{b\in B\setminus A}\mu
=\frac{|A|}{|B|} \cdot \mu+\frac{|B|-|A|}{|B|} \cdot \mu=\frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{a\in A}g(a).$$

Comment: ..You're right.

Comment: Thx your answer. Maybe my explanation is not ver clear. What happen if only allowing $A=[0]$ and $B=[0,1]$.

Comment: @user363851 $A\subset B$ is too weak. Your inequality holds if you assume that if $b\in B\setminus A$ then $b>a$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: @RobertZ thx your suggestion. Is it possible to prove it mathematically?

Comment: @user363851 Yes, see my answer.

Comment: @Robert Z, many thanks.